# Empty popup Leaflet WMS layer

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, javascript, wms, popup

I have make an interactive map with Leaflet and when I click in any point at the basemap  it displays an empty pop-up.
[image]

Here is The code 
map.addEventListener('click', onMapClick);

```
    function onMapClick(e) {

    var latlngStr = '(' + e.latlng.lat.toFixed(3) + ', ' + e.latlng.lng.toFixed(3) + ')';

    //var BBOX = map.getBounds()._southWest.lng+","+map.getBounds()._southWest.lat+","+map.getBounds()._northEast.lng+","
    //+map.getBounds()._northEast.lat;
    var BBOX = map.getBounds().toBBoxString();
    var WIDTH= map.getSize().x;
    var HEIGHT = map.getSize().y;
    var X = map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).x;
    var Y = map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).y;
    var layerObj = {};
    layerObj["cite:Proj_Agadir"] = Projet;
    layerObj["cite:Projets_AssaZag"] =Projets_AssaZag;
    layerObj["cite:Proj_Inzegane"] = Projets_Inzegane; 
    layerObj["cite:Proj_Taroudant"] =Projets_Taroudant;
    layerObj["cite:Proj_Tata"] = Projets_Tata; 
    layerObj["cite:Essaouira"] =Projets_Essaouira;
    layerObj["cite:Export_Output3"] = Projets_Guelmim; 
    layerObj["cite:Chtouka"] =Projet_Chtouka_Ait_Baha;
    layerObj["cite:SidiIfni"] = Projet_Sidi_Ifni; 
    layerObj["cite:Tiznit"] =Projet_Tiznit; 
    layerObj["cite:AEP"] = AEP;
    layerObj["cite:Education"] = Education;
    layerObj["cite:Piste"] =Piste;
    layerObj["cite:Sante"] = Santé;  
    layerObj["cite:AGR"] =AGR;


    queryLayers = [];
    for (key in layerObj) { 
    if(map.hasLayer(layerObj[key])) {
     queryLayers.push(key);
     }
    }
    var urlLayers = queryLayers.join();
    var URL = 'http://localhost:8086/geoserver/cite/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&LAYERS=cite:AEP,cite:Education,cite:Piste,cite:Sante,cite:AGR,cite:Proj_Agadir,cite:Projets_AssaZag,cite:Proj_Inzegane,cite:Proj_Taroudant,cite:Proj_Tata,cite:Essaouira,cite:Export_Output3,cite:Chtouka,cite:SidiIfni,cite:Tiznit&QUERY_LAYERS='+urlLayers+'&STYLES=&BBOX='+BBOX+'&FEATURE_COUNT=5&HEIGHT='+HEIGHT+'&WIDTH='+WIDTH+'&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&INFO_FORMAT=text%2fhtml&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&X='+X+'&Y='+Y;
    popup = new L.Popup({maxWidth: 1000});

    popup.setLatLng(e.latlng);

    popup.setContent("<iframe src='"+URL+"' width='1000' height='200' frameborder='0'></iframe>");

    if (urlLayers)

    map.openPopup(popup);  


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're trying to include the GeoServer WMS GetFeatureInfo for a large number of layers, as HTML, and then to include that as an iframe. I've tested this, and it should work.

I don't have access to your server, so I can't test the URL, but first test that. (You can do that by opening up your web browser's debug tools and watching when you open a popup for the request to go out, and copy and pasting that into a new tab.) If that works, then the issue must be with the code for the iframe. I've included an example that is tested and works here (as a basic web page):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Your Title Here</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<iframe src="https://example.com/geoserver/version2/ows?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetFeatureInfo&layers=example_layer&query_layers=example_layer&feature_count=10&info_format=text/html&format_options=callback%3AhandleJson&SrsName=EPSG%3A4326&width=101&height=101&x=50&y=50&bbox=-36.6625%2C21.679905342529644%2C-36.4625%2C21.879905342529646&time=2018-01-10T23%3A00%3A00.000Z&callback=jQuery22408496475769282517_1515624085509&_=1515624085510" width="1000" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Even better would be to get the results as GeoJSON and format them as a table. That way you get text, and people can select the values. To do this, you use a similar URL, but make set your info_format to `'application/json'`. And when your ajax request returns, you handle parse that JSON into a table.

Comment: Does WMS GetFeatureInfo ever return an image?

Comment: Actually, you're right, @nmtoken. I was distracted by the `format=png` parameter in the URL in the original post. I'll update my response.

Comment: Thank you @AlexLeith  for your answer, but it doesn't work with me, there isn't other solution to display popup for just layers. I tried many tricks but in vain.

Comment: Hey @MERIEMGIS, what happens if you copy and paste your URL into the browser?

Comment: It gives me an exception "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 String index out of range: -1"

Comment: Ok, there you go. See if you can track down the issue with that URL =)